# favicon not cached in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

How does I cache the favicon. i use ExpiresFilter and ExpiresByType of image in web.xml but it not works

```
<filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.Expiresfilter</filter-class>
<init-param>ExpiresByType image<param-name>
```

Comment: Do you get an error, or in which way does it not work?

Comment: no error, but also not cached. I check in F12 of chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things...

You have Expiresfilter in your filter-class. It should be ExpiresFilter (note the uppercase F -- I hope that's just a typo here.

Secondly, you do not seem to have a param-value for your param-name, unless you left it off while posting but actually do have it in code.

Finally your tomcat may not know about the extension of your favicon image. Mostly favicons are of .ico extension. So your tomcat instance needs to know that .ico is an image mimetype. So add this in the web.xml

```
<mime-mapping>
<extension>ico</extension>
<mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
<mime-mapping>
```

If your image is not an .ico, then I am not sure. Let us know.

Comment: @user2258662 You can also vote up the answer if it helped you. Then press the checkbox to accept it. It give the user who answered the question reputation, and you get some as well.